# HandbrakeCLI wont automate via C# process

Tags: c#, process, handbrake

I am trying to automate HandbrakeCLI using C# via the System.Diagnostics.Process class. However, as long as my program is trying to run the process, it seems like the process never advances.

Here is my process setup:

```
Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.FileName = parameters.HandbrakeLocation;
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

string output = string.Empty;
while ((output = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(output);
}
process.WaitForExit();
```

HandbrakeCLI.exe does appear in my processes list. The Debug.WriteLine(output); line continually prints out "Encoding: task 1 of 1, 0.00 %" and the process never completes. If I kill my C# app then HandbrakeCLI instantly shoots up from 7,000k in memory to 145,000k and then does the encoding that I want it to do. Its like my C# app is holding it back.

I have tried to use Read() instead of ReadLine() and I have tried flushing the StandardOutput stream before and after the read with no success. I have a suspicion that since HandbrakeCLI overwrites stdout when it writes the encoding progress, that it won't act like a normal process when automated via C#.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was redirecting stderr to my C# application, but not consuming it. The process was hanging until stderr was consumed.